# ComboBox Editor on a grid cell does not work

Tags: extjs

I am using Ext Js 4.1, and I need to put a comboBox in a grid cell to user choose the parameter that gonna be saved, however the available parameters coming from a store, but it does not working, I am already using editing plugin, as specified in docs, can anyone provide a insight ??

```
storeParameter = Ext.create('ParameterStore');

 {
            header: 'Parameter',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'parameter',
            field: {
                type: 'textfield'
            },
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: storeParameter
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define the **editor** parameter on the **grid** cell where you want it to appear. Seems like you are trying to defining the editor in the store itself.

Comment: No, I am not, the 'editor' is an atributte of the column 'parameter'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I needed to add the attribute in grid:

```
selType: 'cellmodel',
```

And instead of to put a store directly, I replaced for comboBox, which has the store.

```
var comboParameter = Ext.create('ComboBoxParameter');
```

And the column replace to:

```
{
            header: 'Parameter',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'parameter',
            editor: comboParameter
        },
```